# Copy-SPSite is not recognized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm completely new to Sharepoint and was tasked with copying some new sites. However when I opened Sharepoint Management Shell and typed "Copy-SPSite", it displayed the following message
[image]

Also, the Sharepoint Shell says that "***The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered***". So I wonder if anyone has been in this situation and how to get over it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\YourUser**

As well Just run Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\YourUser again and it will set the appropriate permissions.

Follow http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kvosters/archive/2012/11/29/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx